# notepad character decoding

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I am reading text from a notepad opened by my program.and this is my code

```
const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;

[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
extern static int SendMessageGetTextLength(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam,     IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static IntPtr SendMessageGetText(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, [Out] StringBuilder lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

public static string GetText(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("hwnd");
    IntPtr handler = FindWindowEx(hwnd, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
    int length = SendMessageGetTextLength(handler, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (length > 0 && length < int.MaxValue)
    {
        length++;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

        SendMessageGetText(handler, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Length, sb);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

It is getting the text but in a special encoding.
For example, if the text entered is 'hello' it gets '興梀㇨ȿڳㇺ'.
What is the encoding of this text so I can decode it to ASCII?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using notepad as an intermediate step instead of opening the file stream directly?

Comment: yes, i want to get the text while the user is writing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrape text from textbox in Windows application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374531/scrape-text-from-textbox-in-windows-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in fact that you are passing `sb.Length` in the `WM_GETTEXT` message, when in fact you should be passing `sb.Capacity` or even just `length`.

I would do it like this:

```
if (length > 0 && length < int.MaxValue)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length+1);
    SendMessageGetText(handler, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)length+1, sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I'd also point out that `WM_GETTEXT` will not return more than 64k characters to the `length < int.MaxValue` isn't what you need.

---

Of course, in the longer run it may be better to use the Unicode throughout so that you can support international text.

I personally would always opt for using the Unicode APIs and use the following p/invoke declarations:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", 
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
extern static int SendMessageGetTextLength(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage",
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
extern static IntPtr SendMessageGetText(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx",
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
```

Comment: still not working ,I changed the CharSet to Ansi and then I converted the text to UTF8

Comment: Where does UTF8 come into things?

Comment: when calling the GetText method

Comment: Sorry, there is no UTF8 in anything that I can see in the question. It's pretty clear what's wrong with the code in the question. If you are looking at different code from me, then I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: No sir,I am just calling the method

Comment: You are passing `sb.Length` by mistake. It should be `length` or perhaps `sb.Capacity`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're writing in managed code, you may as well use the managed code automation interfaces, which does all the interop for you. Why reinvent the wheel?

```
using System.Windows.Automation;
public static string GetText(IntPtr hwnd)
{
  IntPtr hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
  return (string)AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwndEdit).
     GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
}
```

You can even make the automation do the `FindWindowEx` for you:

```
public static string GetText(IntPtr hwnd)
{
  var editElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd).
                    FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree,
                              new PropertyCondition(
                                     AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Edit"));
  return (string)editElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
}
```